# tutorials refine or filter a php search

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter

Does anyone knows any tutorials on how to refine of filter a php/mysql search after the search has already been made? I have searched google and every possible search engine out there, but nothing.

Thank you in advance

```
<?php
if(isset ($_POST['searchString'])){

    $searchStr = $_POST['searchString'];

    function sanitizeString($searchStr){
        $searchStr = htmlentities($searchStr);
        $searchStr = strip_tags($searchStr);
        $searchStr = htmlspecialchars($searchStr);
        return $searchStr;
    }

    $searchStr = sanitizeString($searchStr);
    $searchStr = str_replace("%", "", $searchStr);
    require_once('Connections/conn.php');


$sql = "SELECT * FROM happyhours
WHERE city LIKE :keyword OR zipcode LIKE :keyword";



    if (!empty($searchStr)){

        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':keyword',$searchStr, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            try{
                $stmt->execute();
                }
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo $ex->getMessage();
                }
    }
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();
        $each = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

?>
```

the following to output results

```
<?php do { ?>

<table id="results" align="left" width="700px" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="5" width="130" id="photo"><a class="lightbox" href='<?php echo $each['imageURL']; ?>'><p><?php echo $each['name']; ?></p><img id="hh-image" src='<?php echo $each['imageURL']; ?>' width="80" height="80" /></a></td>

        <tr><td id="hh-name" style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:16px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'; font-weight:500" width="560" height="20"><?php echo $each['name']; ?></td></tr>

         <tr><td> <a href='<?php echo $each['googleMap']; ?>' target="new" style="font-size:14px"><?php echo $each['address']; ?></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:14px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'" height="20"><?php echo $each['phone']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; font-size:14px; font-family:'Myriad Pro'" height="20"><?php echo $each['dayOfTheWeek']; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;(<?php echo $each['hours']; ?>)</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>


<?php } while($each = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); ?>



<?php  }  ?>
```

Comment: Are you asking for ways to filter further on the results of a *query* that has been made?

Comment: http://datatables.net/

Comment: Are you using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) that has a plugin for this? Maybe you should be?

Comment: wow that's a lot of searching you've done!  Can you show us the code for your php/mysql search?

Comment: @useSticks yes to filter a query that has been made

Comment: @AllInOne  I have posted my code

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't this just be as simple as including a search form in your results page with the previous search terms pre-populated?  Maybe I'm not sure what you mean by "filtering" tho.

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) has a section that provides a brief overview on filtering a return from MYSQLi.  For more detail, I'd suggest checking the [MYSQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) documentation.

(Of course, what I'd really recommend is checking out one of the many frameworks for PHP! - I see that tadman has already provided a link to a good list of them in the comments.)